# A derivative of the inverse of the function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Consider $f(x) = x^3 - 3x^2 - 1$ where $x \geq 2$.

Find derivative for $f^{-1}(x)$ at point where $x = -1 = f(3)$.

I tried getting $f^{-1}(x)$ and then getting the derivative of that but it  th point equal. I also tried getting $f'(x)$ and inverting that was wrong too.

Comment: Hint, note that $f(f^{-1}(x)) = x$.  Now try differentiating both sides using the chain rule.

Answer (score 1):

$$
f (x)=x^3-3x^2-1  \ \ \   
\implies \ \ \  f '(x)= 3x^2-6x \   \ \  \  \ \  \implies \ \ \ \ f '(3) = 9
$$
let : 
$$
f^{−1} = g
$$
so that$$ g(f\:(x))=x\ \ \ \ (\because\ \  g= f^{-1})$$

differentiating wrt x and chain rule:

$
g'(f(x)).f'(x)=1  $
$
\implies g'(f(x))\  =\frac{1}{f'(x)}
$

putting $x=3 \ \implies \  \ \ f(3)=-1    $
$\therefore$    derivative of $g$ at
$ x=-1  $

$g'(-1)=\frac{1}{f'(3)}=\frac{1}{9}  $

now,
$$g = f^{-1}  $$
thus,
$$ \frac{d}{dx} \left(f^{-1}(-1)\right)=\frac{1}{9}$$

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpuAx.png)